# How to exclude folders from downloading using wget?

Tags: linux, directory, wget

How can i exclude folders from being downloaded using wget ? For example if i wanted to download all of the files and folders of a subfolder:

https://index.org has the following folders:

```
Folder1    
  -subfolder1    
    --file1    
  -subfolder2    
    --file2    
  -subfolder3    
    --file3    
Folder2    
  -subfolder1
```

For example I want to download only subfolder 3 from the Folder1.

I tried:

```
wget -r -np https://index.org/Folder1 -X /subfolder1, /subfolder2
```

Comment: my version of wget says `-X,  --exclude-directories=LIST  list of excluded directories.` but it doesn't make clear how you delimit a list. A comma seems reasonable, but I don't think a comma space is. So .. it should work, as long as you don't have spaces between your list items OR maybe you need to use `:` or `;` to delimit. Did you try these.? Good luck.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest directories considered for include/exclude are subdirectories of the target directory. Perhaps `‘--exclude-domains domain-list’` is the only hope.